# How to find rows in a column that start with a specific name?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       { 
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Database Login");
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE row = '" + textBox1.Text + "%' AND row = '%" + textBox2.text + "%'", connection);
        SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (dataReader.Read())
        {
            textBox3.Text = dataReader.GetString(1);
        }

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

For example I have row like:

banana-orange-apple

apple-orange-banana

orange-apple-banana

banana-apple-orange

and I need to output in textBox3 answers where all lines for example start from banana so answers will be about:

banana-orange-apple

banana-apple-orange

But when I press button nothing happen, so where is my mistake, as I understand I use dataReader.Read wrong and maybe my SQL code also wrong?

Comment: Use `LIKE` instead of `=`

Comment: 1) Do not concatenate your query, instead use parameters. 2) `LIKE 'Banana-%'`

Answer (score 4):

The short answer -- change your code to look like the code below. Notice the sql statement uses `LIKE` instead of `=` because you want to use a value that is only a part of the string for which you are looking.

```
    private string GetDataFromRow(string param)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Database Login"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var sql = "SELECT mySpecificColumn FROM table WHERE row LIKE @txt1";

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@txt1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = $"'{param}%'";
                using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var l = new List<string>();
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        var data = dataReader.GetString(0);
                        l.Add(data);
                    }
                    result = string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, l);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

**Assumptions:** 
I will assume (based on the OP) that the search parameter from "textBox1" will provide the value for which you intend to retrieve from your database. In your example "banana". I further assume "textBox2" is actually irrelevant--at least it was in the provided example. I also assume you wish to return the contents of a single column. I will call that column "mySpecificCoulmn". Please replaces that with the actual name of the column from which you wish to retrieve data.

**Code Explained:** 
First you will notice that I take advantage of the `using` blocks. This is important because they help ensure that the objects I open are closed and disposed of properly. `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `DataReader` all implement the `IDisposable` interface--which good practice is to `close` and `dispose` of these objects. Well, the `using` block takes care of that for you.

Next you will notice I use `Parameters` with my `SqlCommand` object. This helps protect against SQL-Injection. It is particularly important to use parameters when accepting input from the user. I used `SqlDBType.VarChar` but yours could be `SqlDBType.NVarChar` or something else. Pick the appropriate `SqlDBType` for the column you are searching in.

Notice that I requested only one column in the Sql statement (mySpecificColumn) instead of using "*". It is cleaner, better form, faster and most importantly, lets me be in control of how the data is returned from the database.

As mentioned above I am only using one search parameter, which in accordance with your example is looking for any value in the column that partially contains "banana". So I use `LIKE` and then add the parameter name "@txt1". Further down in the code we add the `Parameter` to the "command" object and for a `Value` you see that I use interpolation to add the actual search criteria. If we were passing "banana" as the param then the value of the `Parameter` would be 'banana%' which means we want a value that starts with "banana" and anything after that.

Calling `ExecuteReader` returns a `DataReader` object which we read in a `while` loop. In each loop we add the returned value in a `List` of string that we declared at the top of the method.

Finally, using the `string` method `Join` the `List` values are concatenated to make a string that is separated by new lines to match your desired output:

```
banana-orange-apple
banana-apple-orange
```

**Note:** 
Since database queries can take time and block the UI, I strongly suggest that you consider making your code asynchronous using the `Async` versions of the methods above. Since this is an advanced topic I will not go into detail, but simply present an alternative `Async` version of the code above.

```
    private async Task<string> GetDataFromRowAsync(string param)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Database Login"))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            var sql = "SELECT mySpecificColumn FROM table WHERE row LIKE @txt1";

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@txt1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = $"'{param}%'";
                using (var dataReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    var l = new List<string>();
                    while (await dataReader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        var data = dataReader.GetString(0);
                        l.Add(data);
                    }
                    result = string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, l);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Which would be called like:

```
var result = await GetDataFromRowAsync("banana");
```

You would also need to make some changes to the calling method to accommodate the `Async` pattern.

Please let me know if you have any issues or have any questions.

Comment: A very nice answer.